# JQuery AJAX call to web on iOS stopped working using Phonegap web app

Tags: ios, ajax, jquery, cordova

I have an app written in HTML5, Javascript, css3 using PhoneGap to compile for iOS and Android.  It collects survey information and uploads this via Ajax call to online host.  It has been working really well until recently the upload code appeared to stop working.  WELL NOT QUITE!  On the iPad it says successful but in fact nothing ever makes it to the host.  This is VERY strange.  I've tried re-writing the Ajax call based on articles on here but no luck.

iOS - 6.1.3, PhoneGAP 2.7.0, PhoneGap/Adobe Build used.

This is the upload piece...

```
function sendToWeb(){
var errorflag = false;
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT weburl FROM settings", [], function(tx, results){
        var webURL = results.rows.item(0).weburl;
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM surveypretransfer WHERE uploaded = '0'",[], function(tx, results){
                if (results.rows.length == 0) {
                    alert("You have no surveys waiting to upload");
                } else {
                    alert("You have " + results.rows.length + " surveys waiting to upload");
                    for (var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                        var responseURL = webURL + "/feeds/saveinfo.php";
                        var responseString = results.rows.item(i).responsestring;

                        var localid = results.rows.item(i).id;
                        //alert(localid);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: responseString,
                            url: responseURL,
                            timeout: 30000,
                            success: function(data) {
                                alert('Success!' + data.join('\n'));

                            },
                            error: function(data) {
                                alert(data.join('\n'));
                                console.log("Results: " + localid);
                                alert("Error during Upload.  Error is: "+ data.statusText);
                            }
                        }); //ajax
                    }; //for loop
                    alert("You have successfully uploaded "+ results.rows.length + " survey results");
                    tx.executeSql("UPDATE surveypretransfer SET uploaded = '1' WHERE uploaded = '0'");
                }; //if statement
            });  //tx.execute
    }); 
}, errorCB);
}
```

Neither of the two alerts fire when loaded on iPad.  Works fine on Android and has previously worked on iPad so I can't find what has changed.

UPDATE:  Appears that this only applies to WiFi only iPads.  All the 3G ones I tested were fine.  Figure that!

```
Config.XML contains app id = "com.mydomain.myapp" (as an example)
URL for upload is "http://customer.mydomain.com/feeds/saveinfo.php?..."
Also added line 'access origin="http://mydomain.com" subdomains="true" '
```

Still no results.  Is anyone seeing/having similar issues?  Anyone see my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you might want to try `<access origin="http://*.mydomain.com" />`, as iOS is not documented in the [PhoneGap API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide) to support the `subdomain` property.

If that doesn't solve your issues, you will probably want to look into CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). I had issues trying to do a `POST` request from my app to a local port on iOS. The W3C has a [great article on how to enable CORS](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#How_can_I_participate.3F) that will probably help. I know in my case, the system would attempt to do an `OPTIONS` request first, and if it didn't work, the whole thing would fail.

Another tool that you will probably find useful (if not now, in the future) is [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/). You can set up an iPad to proxy through your desktop, and then you will be able to observe all of the requests going to and from the device. This is how I found the `OPTIONS` request noted above.